# Excel/How to compare characters in the cells?

Tags: excel, compare

```
Cell M2 = 301, 302, 303
Cell N2 = 301, 302, 303, 329, 330, 331
```

I have cells that need to be compare characters. What should I put the excel function that compare cell to return the rest of it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give you a formula based on the limited description, in terms of what you would like to compare.

If the values in N always reflect the same as the values in column M plus some extra numbers in the provided format, I would suggest the following formula:

```
=IF(LEN(N2)>LEN(M2),RIGHT(N2,LEN(N2)-LEN(M2)-2),M2)
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I exactly need!

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to rate me if you liked my answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see your example.

Comment: Hey VBA Pete, I was wondering about this. Rather than using calculating numbers of cells, how to compare by Characters? For example, comparing between (301, 911, 302) and (301, 302, 811, 711) so that I can get (911, 811, 711)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for delay answer, network issue's going on here.

Comment: I don't think you can do via a formula, but I would ask it in a new question and maybe somebody else has a suggestion.

Comment: Also this might help: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/15/compare-data-highlight-mismatched-letters-words/

Comment: Sure I will get the new que for this question. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to post what you currently have in order to avoid you post being downvoted :)